# A maximal subgroup containing some proper subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

A proper subgroup $M$ of a group $G$ is called a maximal subgroup if the only subgroups of $G$ which contain $M$ are $M$ and $G$. I want to prove that if $H$ is a proper subgroup of the finite group $G$ then there is a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. I think that a constructive proof should be used but I don't have any further idea. Please give me any advice.

Comment: If $G$ is finite then obviously there is no infinite ascending sequence of subgroups containing $H$ so there must be a maximal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a finite number of steps since $\;|G|<\infty\;$ : if $\;H\;$ is not *proper* maximal in $\;G\;$ , then there exists $\;H_1\le\;\;s.t.\;\;H\lneqq H_1\;$ . If $\;H_1\;$ is not proper maximal then there exists $\;H_2\le G\;\;s.t.\;\;H_1\lneqq H_2\;$ , and etc.

Comment: Or you could choose a proper subgroup $M$ such that $H \leq M$ and $|M|$ is as large as possible.

Comment: Well, the "as largest as possible" has at least two problems: how do you choose that?, and what if $\;M=G\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Mikko did say proper.

Comment: Indeed @PedroTamaroff, missed that one...but the first problem remains.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Well, this is not a constructive solution. But since the order $G$ is finite, such an $M$ exists.

Comment: I think it is, @MikkoKorhonen...but not explicitly: $\;H\lneqq G\;$ not maximal $\;\implies\;\exists\,g\in G\setminus H\;$ , so that $\;\langle H,g\rangle \lneqq G\;$ (not that **all** such elements $\;g\;$ shall fulfill this, but *at least one* must), and etc.